# Unable to implement Turn Socket for File transfer in iOS Using XMPP

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, file-transfer, xmppframework

I am using below code for creating turn Socket but every time it goes in turnSocketDidFail method so whats the wrong in the code , please help me out.

```
XMPPJID *JID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"9107@test.com/110s-Mac-mini"];

[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:JID.domain, nil]];
TURNSocket *socket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[[NDAppDelegate shareAppDelegateInstance] xmppStream] toJID:JID];
[socket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");


}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");


}
```